# What is this pipe near gutter?

Tags: pipe, gutters

I just bought a house and there is this pipe near a gutter. Any idea what it might be or how I would go about finding out?

[image: what's this pipe?]

Comment: It could be that the gutter down spout once drained into it.

Comment: The downspout drain is probably the correct assessment. You could direct your current downspout into it, **BUT** there's no telling where that pipe goes, whether it's still intact, and what will happen to water that goes down there. May be worth investigating with a camera.

Comment: If it's a drain...it comes out somewhere....downhill.   You could stick a hose at full blast down it and then look for where the water is coming out.   If clogged, a plumbers snake should clear it.

Comment: But if it's collapsed or clogged by roots then it will need replacement before you can use it again

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alaska man+
I had had flip houses we just dropped the new gutter downspouts next to the drain why would we do this?
it is common for these drains to fill with the gravel from shingles and leaves They almost have to be dug up to get them open once plugged,

Many years ago we tried jetting from the street discharge and from the house side thinking it was just leaves but the shingle gravel did not move and we almost got the jet head stuck , after that we just did not mess with them if they were plugged.

You may have luck working a hose in from both ends but my experience is a section will need to be dug up and cleared to get them to work again.

Comment: Draining downspouts into sewers overloaded sewer systems and ( in the Chicago area) several towns required them to be disconnected.

Comment: I don’t see a difference in most cases , the ground absorbs some water then runs to the street, that’s where our lines discharge in town. But it could have been a requirement. I have regularly found them plugged.

Comment: If these drains run into the sewer system, that could be a significant violation and why it's no longer used. If it just directs the water to the curb where it would then run into the storm drains, it's a good thing (assuming that it's not clogged).

Comment: Is it likely that it is still a connection to a sewer if I have private septic. Is there a chance chance it's an abandoned French drain?

Comment: Sam I have installed quite a few French drains I do not usually have an above ground pipe for them, possibly a dry well for runoff but that depends on the local soil conditions.